# Can't connect JS script Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension

Hello there! I have a problem while adding socket.io.js to Chrome extension, it doesn't go well! I have tried like this

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'socket.io.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

But it doesn't work, it is only attaching on HTML (I saw in Dev tools networking), but console still says **Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined**. What can I do?

Code:
manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test app",
  "permissions": [ "background", "tts", "storage" ],

  "background": { "scripts": ["my.js"] },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "my.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["socket.io.js", "my.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

my.js

```
console.log("hey");


var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'socket.io.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
var script2 = document.createElement('script');
script2.src = 'smart.js';
script2.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script2);
```

smart.js

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Client connected');
});
```

my.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="my.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

How to get it work?
**P.S. sockets.io.js is located in the same directory as all of this scripts**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the first script to be loaded.

my.js:

```
(function(d, s, id){
  if (d.getElementById(id)){ return; } // exec only once
  var js1 = d.createElement(s); 
  js1.id = id;
  js1.onload = function(){
    console.log("js1 is ready");
    var js2 = document.createElement(s);
    js2.src = 'smart.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js2);
  };
  console.log("loading js1");
  js1.src = "socket.io.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js1);
}(document, 'script', 'some unique id'));
```